# NDepend Task for Nant

Tags: nant, ndepend

I am in process of creating a Nant BuildFile which will use MSBuild, Nunit, Ncover and Ndepend for compilation, unit test, code coverage and Code quality check. I am not able to find any task for Ndepend in Nant. It would be helpful if someone can share the task syntax.

Regards
Anuj

Comment: Can you invoke what you need from the command line?  If so, you can just use the `exec` task to run it

Comment: [The website](http://www.ndepend.com/docs/getting-started-with-ndepend) also mentions you should have a text file that may be of use: _"Integrate the NDepend report in your daily build process. Facilities are provided for both MSBuild and NAnt build technologies. Read the ReadMe.txt files contained in the .\MSBuild\ and .\NAnt\ folders."_

Comment: Thanks for the inputs James!! I thought about it, but I was not able to find any precise documentation for the command line utility. I have asked my team to purchase a license and do not have the executable to hit and try as of now.

Comment: I did find this CCNet integration though
      <ndepend>
      <project>..\myProject.ndproj</project>
      <executable>C:\tools\ndepend\NDepend.Console.exe</executable>
      <description>Run the NDepend analysis.</description>
      <emitXml>true</emitXml>
      <outputDir>NDepend</outputDir>
      <inputDirs>
        <inputDir>..\myProject\bin\Debug</inputDir>
      </inputDirs>
      <silent>false</silent>
      <reportXslt>custom-report.xsl</reportXslt>
      <timeout>120</timeout>
      <baseDir></baseDir>
      <publish>true</publish>
    </ndepend>

need to chk arg to pass in order

Comment: I will wait for the installation of the tools then and check the readme doc. Meanwhile would appreciate if anyone has already implemented  this and can share the syntax. I will post the details once I have a functional setup.

Comment: Here is the link which has the syntax:
http://ncodex.googlecode.com/svn/tags/0.3.0.50/Build/Packages/nDepend/bin/NAnt/ReadMe.txt

Answer (score 0):

The command line options are available at:
http://www.ndepend.com/docs/ndepend-console

These can be executed through Nant scripts as mentioned in below link:

http://ncodex.googlecode.com/svn/tags/0.3.0.50/Build/Packages/nDepend/bin/NAnt/ReadMe.txt

There is just one mandatory argument. All other arguments can be passed in any order.

It is a popular tool and I am surprised not many posts are available. I missed the command line argument page in NDepend site because it is by the heading NDepend Console. Hope it helps others going forward!!

Comment: In case it helps others, someone posted the code for an NDepend task a decade before this question: https://davidohara.wordpress.com/2005/10/28/ndepend-task-for-nant/  I don't know whether you found that or whether it was any use.